# Salesforce CRM Link

Tags: salesforce

I just started working with Salesforce CRM.

For different opportunities, we have a relevant ID which is stored in a field.

I would like to add a link to the opportunity and I will be able to send a post request through this link using the ID.

The reqest process:
The target website is  https://www.efast.dol.gov/portal/app/disseminate?execution=e1s1

An ID will be filled into EIN textbox. and "Search" button is clicked.

Does anyone have a suggestion or tutorial reference for me?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could compose the url in a formula field ? Question is not entirely clear and may be easier to answer with more explanation.

Comment: Sdry, the url is unknown, I posted another one and please take a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639513/salesforce-crm-link-to-post-a-request